# How to cut the 20 characters at the end of specific lines while keeping all the other lines intact in the output in bash

Tags: bash, bioinformatics, fasta, fastq

So I have a FASTA file that looks like this which I have split in files of 2 lines

```
\>H.Sapiens.1M.Illumina.low.000000000/1
CTCCTTGCCTCATCCTCCCAAATAGCATGCACCACCACGCGCAGCTAATTT
\>H.Sapiens.1M.Illumina.low.000000000/2
AGGCTGAGATAAGAATATAATAGGACAAAAAACAAGATTTTCAGTTTCAAA
\>H.Sapiens.1M.Illumina.low.000000001/1
AGATAGCCCTTCAAAGGAGTTTCATCATCTTTACGGGAGGTTATCTAACAA
\>H.Sapiens.1M.Illumina.low.000000001/2
TTAAGATTTCGAGGAGTCAAAAGGTGTATGTGGACTTTCAACTGCAGGGGG
```

And a FASTQ file that I have split in files of 4 lines

```
@H.Sapiens.1M.Illumina.l100.low.000000000/1
CTCCTTGCCTCATCCTCCCAAATAGCATGCACCACCACGCGCAGCTAATTT
+
KGOLHSAHTEFKMLGJPENFEGMIDAHKMIJFIEIHKCFCGHEGMJGHHPH
@H.Sapiens.1M.Illumina.l100.low.000000000/2
AGGCTGAGATAAGAATATAATAGGACAAAAAACAAGATTTTCAGTTTCAAA
+
IHHHIIIIHHIHHIHIIHHGFKGGIHGJGEIIFEEGIBHJKKJJIJJEJJF
```

and I need a bash script that can cut 20 characters at the end of the second line for FASTA and 20 characters at the end of the second and the fourth line for FASTQ while keeping the rest of the lines intact in the output.
How could I do it?

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Also, could you please format your post so it is more readable ?

Comment: Why are there backslashes (`\>`) in your fasta headers?

Comment: @tripleee It looks like one of the typical simple bioinformatics questions. It has broad applications, especially for new users. It is not "too broad", IMO, and had "enough detail" for at least 2 answers (by you and choroba). If it is put on hold, it might be because the OP showed no code or commands that they tried so far. But I am not sure if this is a widely enforced reason for hold, especially for new users.

Comment: Try a Perl one-liner, e.g.: `perl -lpe 'if ( $. % 2 == 0 ) { s{.{20}\z}{}; }' input_fastq_or_fasta_file` Here, it assumes that your fasta file has only 2 lines per sequence. Note that in general, this is not always the case. The one-liner uses the code provided inline (`-e` flag). It reads 1 line at a time and prints each line at the end (`-p`). It `chomp`'s (strips the newline chars) after reading and adds them before printing (`-l`). Inside, it replaces the 20 chars at the end of the line (`\z`) with nothing. `$.` (line number) test makes it work on lines 2, 4, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In GNU sed, you can use the `~` address which specifies every n-th line:

```
sed '2~2 s/\(.*\).\{20\}/\1/' file
```

The command means

- `2~2` start on line 2, apply on every 2nd line
- `s/PATTERN/REPLACE/` is the substitution
- `.\{20\}` matches 20 characters
- `\(.*\)` remembers any characters before the 20 ones
- `\1` is the first remembered group

Comment: Combine with `split -l4 <(...)` for fastq files of four lines.

Answer (score 0):

With Awk, it's easy to say "do this on lines which don't match the regular expression `/^>/`" (for FASTA) or "on lines 1 and 3 after a line matching `/^@/`" (for FASTQ). The operation to truncate the last 20 characters can be expressed in different ways, so let me show two different alternatives.

```
awk '!/^>/ { sub (/.{20}$/, ""); } 1' file.fasta
```

uses a regular expression substitution; or

```
awk '/^@/ { n=NR }
    NR==n+1 || NR==n+3 { $0 = substr($0, 1, length($0)-20) } 1' file.fastq
```

replaces every selected line with a substring of itself.

I would go with the former as more succinct and elegant; but the explicitness of the latter has some merit, too, in that it is by and large self-documenting.

Online demo: https://ideone.com/la3DDT